# Unable to find an element with cdk-overlay-container

Tags: angular, selenium

I have an angular project which has a cdk-overlay-container on this there is a pop-up and I want to click button on that pop-up and get text.

Tried multiple xpath, actions, handles but it didn't work. I suspect this might got to do somthing with this container. Did someone face with similar issue?

[image]

Adding html.... the element to click is either the highlight or h4
[image]

Comment: Can you please paste the HTML image till the text you wanna extract.

Comment: @irfansoudagar Update the question with the text based relevant HTML of the `cdk-overlay-container` including the text you want to extract.

Comment: @DebanjanB added html

Comment: @SwaroopHumane added html

Answer (score 0):

I dont know angular, i have only used python so far, but you can either use alert(driver).accept()/ alert.(driver).dismiss(), or you use, in case of python, pyautogui to click on the respective button manually.

Comment: this is does not help at all?

Comment: I did definitely write this over a year ago, and since selenium has similar implementations in every coding language it actually is helpful.